# Как сделать вывод из функции в 2 столбца js

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Пишу сайт для проекта в вузе,нужно чтобы информация считывалась из обоих окошек ввода, и  при нажатии на "сравнить" выводилась в 2 столбца под этими, но всегда выводится только 1 столбец, чую что проблема в innerHTML. Но как решить, идей никаких. Если есть возможность решить небольшим перекраиванием кода буду очень рад, ибо переписывать всё с нуля, вообще неохота :)

```css
body {
  background-color: #2b2b2e;
}

P {
  font-size: 15pt;
  Font-family: roboto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25pt;
  Font-family: roboto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 50px 30px 50px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  Font-family: roboto;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 630px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 15pt;
  Font-family: roboto;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  Font-family: roboto;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 5px 25px 20px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  Font-family: roboto;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 30px 50px 25px 50px;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  Font-family: roboto;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 5px 25px 640px;
}

nav {
  font-size: 15pt;
  Font-family: roboto;
}

.div1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 50px 25px 350px;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="div1"> <input id="elem1" type="text" list="camsbegin" name="list"></h5>
<h5 class="div2"> <input id="elem2" type="text" list="camsbegin" name="list2"> </h5>
<div1 id="cmp"> <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()" /></div>
  <script>
    function compare() {
      var a = document.getElementById('elem1').value;
      if (a == "Nikon D5300") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h3>Год выпуска</h3><h4>2013</h4><h3>Байонет</h3><h4>Nikon F</h4><h3>Ресурс затвора</h3><h4>250000</h4><h3>Кроп фактор</h3><h4>1.5</h4><h3>Разрешение</h3><h4>24MP</h4><h3>Низкочастотный фильтр</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Размер пикселя</h3><h4>3.9НМ</h4><h3>Глубина цвета</h3><h4>24</h4><h3>Динамический диапазон</h3><h4>13,9</h4><h3>Исо темноты</h3><h4>1338</h4><h3>Размер экрана</h3><h4>1036800 пикселей</h4><h3>Точки автофокусировки</h3><h4>39</h4><h3>Покрытие видоискателя</h3><h4>23%</h4><h3>Матричная стабилизация</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Скорость съёмки</h3><h4>5 кадров/секунду</h4><h3>Диапазон исо</h3><h4>100-25600</h4><h3>Ресурс батареи</h3><h4>600</h4>';
      if (a == "Nikon D3300") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h3>Год выпуска</h3><h4>2014</h4><h3>Байонет</h3><h4>Nikon F</h4><h3>Ресурс затвора</h3><h4>250000</h4><h3>Кроп фактор</h3><h4>1.5</h4><h3>Разрешение</h3><h4>24MP</h4><h3>Низкочастотный фильтр</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Размер пикселя</h3><h4>3.9НМ</h4><h3>Глубина цвета</h3><h4>24,3</h4><h3>Динамический диапазон</h3><h4>13,9</h4><h3>Исо темноты</h3><h4>1358</h4><h3>Размер экрана</h3><h4>921600 пикселей</h4><h3>Точки автофокусировки</h3><h4>11</h4><h3>Покрытие видоискателя</h3><h4>17%</h4><h3>Матричная стабилизация</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Скорость съёмки</h3><h4>5 кадров/секунду</h4><h3>Диапазон исо</h3><h4>100-25600</h4><h3>Ресурс батареи</h3><h4>700</h4>';
      if (a == "Nikon D5500") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h3>Год выпуска</h3><h4>2015</h4><h3>Байонет</h3><h4>Nikon F</h4><h3>Ресурс затвора</h3><h4>250000</h4><h3>Кроп фактор</h3><h4>1.5</h4><h3>Разрешение</h3><h4>24,2MP</h4><h3>Низкочастотный фильтр</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Размер пикселя</h3><h4>3.9НМ</h4><h3>Глубина цвета</h3><h4>24,1</h4><h3>Динамический диапазон</h3><h4>14</h4><h3>Исо темноты</h3><h4>1438</h4><h3>Размер экрана</h3><h4>1036800 пикселей</h4><h3>Точки автофокусировки</h3><h4>39</h4><h3>Покрытие видоискателя</h3><h4>23%</h4><h3>Матричная стабилизация</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Скорость съёмки</h3><h4>5 кадров/секунду</h4><h3>Диапазон исо</h3><h4>100-25600</h4><h3>Ресурс батареи</h3><h4>820</h4>';
      if (a == "Nikon D3500") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h3>Год выпуска</h3><h4>2018</h4><h3>Байонет</h3><h4>Nikon F</h4><h3>Ресурс затвора</h3><h4>250000</h4><h3>Кроп фактор</h3><h4>1.5</h4><h3>Разрешение</h3><h4>24,2MP</h4><h3>Низкочастотный фильтр</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Размер пикселя</h3><h4>3.9НМ</h4><h3>Глубина цвета</h3><h4>24,3</h4><h3>Динамический диапазон</h3><h4>14</h4><h3>Исо темноты</h3><h4>1438</h4><h3>Размер экрана</h3><h4>1036800 пикселей</h4><h3>Точки автофокусировки</h3><h4>11</h4><h3>Покрытие видоискателя</h3><h4>17%</h4><h3>Матричная стабилизация</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Скорость съёмки</h3><h4>5 кадров/секунду</h4><h3>Диапазон исо</h3><h4>100-25600</h4><h3>Ресурс батареи</h3><h4>1250</h4>';
      if (a == "Nikon Z50") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h3>Год выпуска</h3><h4>2019</h4><h3>Байонет</h3><h4>Nikon Z</h4><h3>Ресурс затвора</h3><h4>250000</h4><h3>Кроп фактор</h3><h4>1.5</h4><h3>Разрешение</h3><h4>20,9MP</h4><h3>Низкочастотный фильтр</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Размер пикселя</h3><h4>3.5НМ</h4><h3>Глубина цвета</h3><h4>28,5</h4><h3>Динамический диапазон</h3><h4>17</h4><h3>Исо темноты</h3><h4>2244</h4><h3>Размер экрана</h3><h4>921600 пикселей</h4><h3>Точки автофокусировки</h3><h4>209</h4><h3>Покрытие видоискателя</h3><h4>92%</h4><h3>Матричная стабилизация</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Скорость съёмки</h3><h4>1 кадров/секунду</h4><h3>Диапазон исо</h3><h4>100-102400</h4><h3>Ресурс батареи</h3><h4>280</h4>';
      if (a == "Canon 4000D") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h3>Год выпуска</h3><h4>2018</h4><h3>Байонет</h3><h4>Canon EF / EF-S</h4><h3>Ресурс затвора</h3><h4>250000</h4><h3>Кроп фактор</h3><h4>1.6</h4><h3>Разрешение</h3><h4>18MP</h4><h3>Низкочастотный фильтр</h3><h4>Есть</h4><h3>Размер пикселя</h3><h4>4,3НМ</h4><h3>Глубина цвета</h3><h4>21,9</h4><h3>Динамический диапазон</h3><h4>11,4</h4><h3>Исо темноты</h3><h4>695</h4><h3>Размер экрана</h3><h4>230400 пикселей</h4><h3>Точки автофокусировки</h3><h4>9</h4><h3>Покрытие видоискателя</h3><h4>13%</h4><h3>Матричная стабилизация</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Скорость съёмки</h3><h4>3 кадра/секунду</h4><h3>Диапазон исо</h3><h4>100-6400</h4><h3>Ресурс батареи</h3><h4>500</h4>';
      if (a == "Canon 2000D") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h3>Год выпуска</h3><h4>2018</h4><h3>Байонет</h3><h4>Canon EF / EF-S</h4><h3>Ресурс затвора</h3><h4>250000</h4><h3>Кроп фактор</h3><h4>1.6</h4><h3>Разрешение</h3><h4>24,1MP</h4><h3>Низкочастотный фильтр</h3><h4>Есьб</h4><h3>Размер пикселя</h3><h4>3,7НМ</h4><h3>Глубина цвета</h3><h4>22,6</h4><h3>Динамический диапазон</h3><h4>11,9</h4><h3>Исо темноты</h3><h4>1009</h4><h3>Размер экрана</h3><h4>921600 пикселей</h4><h3>Точки автофокусировки</h3><h4>9</h4><h3>Покрытие видоискателя</h3><h4>13%</h4><h3>Матричная стабилизация</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Скорость съёмки</h3><h4>3 кадра/секунду</h4><h3>Диапазон исо</h3><h4>100-6400</h4><h3>Ресурс батареи</h3><h4>500</h4>';
      if (a == "Canon 250D") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h3>Год выпуска</h3><h4>2019</h4><h3>Байонет</h3><h4>Canon EF / EF-S</h4><h3>Ресурс затвора</h3><h4>250000</h4><h3>Кроп фактор</h3><h4>1.6</h4><h3>Разрешение</h3><h4>24,1MP</h4><h3>Низкочастотный фильтр</h3><h4>Есьб</h4><h3>Размер пикселя</h3><h4>3,7НМ</h4><h3>Глубина цвета</h3><h4>21,6</h4><h3>Динамический диапазон</h3><h4>13,9</h4><h3>Исо темноты</h3><h4>1250</h4><h3>Размер экрана</h3><h4>1036800 пикселей</h4><h3>Точки автофокусировки</h3><h4>9</h4><h3>Покрытие видоискателя</h3><h4>13%</h4><h3>Матричная стабилизация</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Скорость съёмки</h3><h4>5 кадра/секунду</h4><h3>Диапазон исо</h3><h4>100-51200</h4><h3>Ресурс батареи</h3><h4>1070</h4>';
      if (a == "Canon 850D") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h3>Год выпуска</h3><h4>2020</h4><h3>Байонет</h3><h4>Canon EF / EF-S</h4><h3>Ресурс затвора</h3><h4>250000</h4><h3>Кроп фактор</h3><h4>1.6</h4><h3>Разрешение</h3><h4>24,1MP</h4><h3>Низкочастотный фильтр</h3><h4>Есьб</h4><h3>Размер пикселя</h3><h4>3,7НМ</h4><h3>Глубина цвета</h3><h4>22,6</h4><h3>Динамический диапазон</h3><h4>14,2</h4><h3>Исо темноты</h3><h4>1850</h4><h3>Размер экрана</h3><h4>1036800 пикселей</h4><h3>Точки автофокусировки</h3><h4>45</h4><h3>Покрытие видоискателя</h3><h4>32%</h4><h3>Матричная стабилизация</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Скорость съёмки</h3><h4>7 кадра/секунду</h4><h3>Диапазон исо</h3><h4>100-51200</h4><h3>Ресурс батареи</h3><h4>800</h4>';
      var a = document.getElementById('elem2').value;
      if (a == "Nikon D5300") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h2>Год выпуска</h2><h6>2013</h6><h2>Байонет</h2><h6>Nikon F</h6><h2>Ресурс затвора</h2><h6>250000</h6><h2>Кроп фактор</h2><h6>1.5</h6><h2>Разрешение</h2><h6>24MP</h6><h2>Низкочастотный фильтр</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Размер пикселя</h2><h6>3.9НМ</h6><h2>Глубина цвета</h2><h6>24</h6><h2>Динамический диапазон</h2><h6>13,9</h6><h2>Исо темноты</h2><h6>1338</h6><h2>Размер экрана</h2><h6>1036800 пикселей</h6><h2>Точки автофокусировки</h2><h6>39</h6><h2>Покрытие видоискателя</h2><h6>23%</h6><h2>Матричная стабилизация</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Скорость съёмки</h2><h6>5 кадров/секунду</h6><h2>Диапазон исо</h2><h6>100-25600</h6><h2>Ресурс батареи</h2><h6>600</h6>';
      if (a == "Nikon D3300") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h2>Год выпуска</h2><h6>2014</h6><h2>Байонет</h2><h6>Nikon F</h6><h2>Ресурс затвора</h2><h6>250000</h6><h2>Кроп фактор</h2><h6>1.5</h6><h2>Разрешение</h2><h6>24MP</h6><h2>Низкочастотный фильтр</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Размер пикселя</h2><h6>3.9НМ</h6><h2>Глубина цвета</h2><h6>24,3</h6><h2>Динамический диапазон</h2><h6>13,9</h6><h2>Исо темноты</h2><h6>1358</h6><h2>Размер экрана</h2><h6>921600 пикселей</h6><h2>Точки автофокусировки</h2><h6>11</h6><h2>Покрытие видоискателя</h2><h6>17%</h6><h2>Матричная стабилизация</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Скорость съёмки</h2><h6>5 кадров/секунду</h6><h2>Диапазон исо</h2><h6>100-25600</h6><h2>Ресурс батареи</h2><h6>700</h6>';
      if (a == "Nikon D5500") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h2>Год выпуска</h2><h6>2015</h6><h2>Байонет</h2><h6>Nikon F</h6><h2>Ресурс затвора</h2><h6>250000</h6><h2>Кроп фактор</h2><h6>1.5</h6><h2>Разрешение</h2><h6>24,2MP</h6><h2>Низкочастотный фильтр</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Размер пикселя</h2><h6>3.9НМ</h6><h2>Глубина цвета</h2><h6>24,1</h6><h2>Динамический диапазон</h2><h6>14</h6><h2>Исо темноты</h2><h6>1438</h6><h2>Размер экрана</h2><h6>1036800 пикселей</h6><h2>Точки автофокусировки</h2><h6>39</h6><h2>Покрытие видоискателя</h2><h6>23%</h6><h2>Матричная стабилизация</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Скорость съёмки</h2><h6>5 кадров/секунду</h6><h2>Диапазон исо</h2><h6>100-25600</h6><h2>Ресурс батареи</h2><h6>820</h6>';
      if (a == "Nikon D3500") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h2>Год выпуска</h2><h6>2018</h6><h2>Байонет</h2><h6>Nikon F</h6><h2>Ресурс затвора</h2><h6>250000</h6><h2>Кроп фактор</h2><h6>1.5</h6><h2>Разрешение</h2><h6>24,2MP</h6><h2>Низкочастотный фильтр</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Размер пикселя</h2><h6>3.9НМ</h6><h2>Глубина цвета</h2><h6>24,3</h6><h2>Динамический диапазон</h2><h6>14</h6><h2>Исо темноты</h2><h6>1438</h6><h2>Размер экрана</h2><h6>1036800 пикселей</h6><h2>Точки автофокусировки</h2><h6>11</h6><h2>Покрытие видоискателя</h2><h6>17%</h6><h2>Матричная стабилизация</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Скорость съёмки</h2><h6>5 кадров/секунду</h6><h2>Диапазон исо</h2><h6>100-25600</h6><h2>Ресурс батареи</h2><h6>1250</h6>';
      if (a == "Nikon Z50") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h2>Год выпуска</h2><h6>2019</h6><h2>Байонет</h2><h6>Nikon Z</h6><h2>Ресурс затвора</h2><h6>250000</h6><h2>Кроп фактор</h2><h6>1.5</h6><h2>Разрешение</h2><h6>20,9MP</h6><h2>Низкочастотный фильтр</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Размер пикселя</h2><h6>3.5НМ</h6><h2>Глубина цвета</h2><h6>28,5</h6><h2>Динамический диапазон</h2><h6>17</h6><h2>Исо темноты</h2><h6>2244</h6><h2>Размер экрана</h2><h6>921600 пикселей</h6><h2>Точки автофокусировки</h2><h6>209</h6><h2>Покрытие видоискателя</h2><h6>92%</h6><h2>Матричная стабилизация</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Скорость съёмки</h2><h6>1 кадров/секунду</h6><h2>Диапазон исо</h2><h6>100-102400</h6><h2>Ресурс батареи</h2><h6>280</h6>';
      if (a == "Canon 4000D") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h2>Год выпуска</h2><h6>2018</h6><h2>Байонет</h2><h6>Canon EF / EF-S</h6><h2>Ресурс затвора</h2><h6>250000</h6><h2>Кроп фактор</h2><h6>1.6</h6><h2>Разрешение</h2><h6>18MP</h6><h2>Низкочастотный фильтр</h2><h6>Есть</h6><h2>Размер пикселя</h2><h6>4,3НМ</h6><h2>Глубина цвета</h2><h6>21,9</h6><h2>Динамический диапазон</h2><h6>11,4</h6><h2>Исо темноты</h2><h6>695</h6><h2>Размер экрана</h2><h6>230400 пикселей</h6><h2>Точки автофокусировки</h2><h6>9</h6><h2>Покрытие видоискателя</h2><h6>13%</h6><h2>Матричная стабилизация</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Скорость съёмки</h2><h6>3 кадра/секунду</h6><h2>Диапазон исо</h2><h6>100-6400</h6><h2>Ресурс батареи</h2><h6>500</h6>';
      if (a == "Canon 2000D") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h2>Год выпуска</h2><h6>2018</h6><h2>Байонет</h2><h6>Canon EF / EF-S</h6><h2>Ресурс затвора</h2><h6>250000</h6><h2>Кроп фактор</h2><h6>1.6</h6><h2>Разрешение</h2><h6>24,1MP</h6><h2>Низкочастотный фильтр</h2><h6>Есьб</h6><h2>Размер пикселя</h2><h6>3,7НМ</h6><h2>Глубина цвета</h2><h6>22,6</h6><h2>Динамический диапазон</h2><h6>11,9</h6><h2>Исо темноты</h2><h6>1009</h6><h2>Размер экрана</h2><h6>921600 пикселей</h6><h2>Точки автофокусировки</h2><h6>9</h6><h2>Покрытие видоискателя</h2><h6>13%</h6><h2>Матричная стабилизация</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Скорость съёмки</h2><h6>3 кадра/секунду</h6><h2>Диапазон исо</h2><h6>100-6400</h6><h2>Ресурс батареи</h2><h6>500</h6>';
      if (a == "Canon 250D") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h2>Год выпуска</h2><h6>2019</h6><h2>Байонет</h2><h6>Canon EF / EF-S</h6><h2>Ресурс затвора</h2><h6>250000</h6><h2>Кроп фактор</h2><h6>1.6</h6><h2>Разрешение</h2><h6>24,1MP</h6><h2>Низкочастотный фильтр</h2><h6>Есьб</h6><h2>Размер пикселя</h2><h6>3,7НМ</h6><h2>Глубина цвета</h2><h6>21,6</h6><h2>Динамический диапазон</h2><h6>13,9</h6><h2>Исо темноты</h2><h6>1250</h6><h2>Размер экрана</h2><h6>1036800 пикселей</h6><h2>Точки автофокусировки</h2><h6>9</h6><h2>Покрытие видоискателя</h2><h6>13%</h6><h2>Матричная стабилизация</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Скорость съёмки</h2><h6>5 кадра/секунду</h6><h2>Диапазон исо</h2><h6>100-51200</h6><h2>Ресурс батареи</h2><h6>1070</h6>';
      if (a == "Canon 850D") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h2>Год выпуска</h2><h6>2020</h6><h2>Байонет</h2><h6>Canon EF / EF-S</h6><h2>Ресурс затвора</h2><h6>250000</h6><h2>Кроп фактор</h2><h6>1.6</h6><h2>Разрешение</h2><h6>24,1MP</h6><h2>Низкочастотный фильтр</h2><h6>Есьб</h6><h2>Размер пикселя</h2><h6>3,7НМ</h6><h2>Глубина цвета</h2><h6>22,6</h6><h2>Динамический диапазон</h2><h6>14,2</h6><h2>Исо темноты</h2><h6>1850</h6><h2>Размер экрана</h2><h6>1036800 пикселей</h6><h2>Точки автофокусировки</h2><h6>45</h6><h2>Покрытие видоискателя</h2><h6>32%</h6><h2>Матричная стабилизация</h2><h6>Нет</h6><h2>Скорость съёмки</h2><h6>7 кадра/секунду</h6><h2>Диапазон исо</h2><h6>100-51200</h6><h2>Ресурс батареи</h2><h6>800</h6>';
    }
  </script>
  <datalist id="camsbegin">
  <option value="">
  <option value="Nikon D5300">
  <option value="Nikon D3300">
  <option value="Nikon D5500">
  <option value="Nikon D3500">
  <option value="Nikon Z50">
  <option value="Canon 4000D">
  <option value="Canon 2000D">
  <option value="Canon 250D">
  <option value="Canon 850D">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Я бы вам за такое максимум тройку поставил :) `div1` - это что за тег такой новый?  Сделайте массив с данными, уберите кучу `if`.

Answer (score 0):

> Если есть возможность решить небольшим перекраиванием кода

Небольшим, тут похоже не получится. По-хорошему, переписать бы всё. На том же codepen должны быть уже готовые решения вашей задачи. Чтобы выстроить в 2 колонки и разместить под выводом, можно решить задачу флексами, например так:

```css
.form-container {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 50%;
}
.flex-item {
   background-color: green;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
<input type="text" class = 'one'>
<input type="text" class = 'two'>
<button>press me!</button>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-item">1</div>
   <div class="flex-item">2</div>
   <div class="flex-item">3</div>
   <div class="flex-item">4</div>
   <div class="flex-item">5</div>
   <div class="flex-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Просто вставляйте характеристики техники в айтемы и всё.

вот тут

```
<div1 id="cmp"> <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()" /></div>
```

лучше сделать так: инпут отдельно, див отдельно.

```
<input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()" /><div id="cmp"></div>
```

и тогда не нужно каждый раз создавать тут кнопку

```
if (a == "Nikon D5300") cmp.innerHTML = ' <input type="button" value="сравнить" onclick="compare()">.<br><h3>Год выпуска</h3><h4>2013</h4><h3>Байонет</h3><h4>Nikon F</h4><h3>Ресурс затвора</h3><h4>250000</h4><h3>Кроп фактор</h3><h4>1.5</h4><h3>Разрешение</h3><h4>24MP</h4><h3>Низкочастотный фильтр</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Размер пикселя</h3><h4>3.9НМ</h4><h3>Глубина цвета</h3><h4>24</h4><h3>Динамический диапазон</h3><h4>13,9</h4><h3>Исо темноты</h3><h4>1338</h4><h3>Размер экрана</h3><h4>1036800 пикселей</h4><h3>Точки автофокусировки</h3><h4>39</h4><h3>Покрытие видоискателя</h3><h4>23%</h4><h3>Матричная стабилизация</h3><h4>Нет</h4><h3>Скорость съёмки</h3><h4>5 кадров/секунду</h4><h3>Диапазон исо</h3><h4>100-25600</h4><h3>Ресурс батареи</h3><h4>600</h4>';
```